# UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive changing tableview height with keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit, uikeyboard

Within a `UIViewController` I've set
`self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive`.

This is great because the user can drag the keyboard down from the tableview.

However, the tableview maintains it's current height when dragging down the keyboard. This looks odd because it leaves empty space between the keyboard and the scrollview.

How can I persistently track the frame of the keyboard so I may resize the tableview as the user drags the keyboard? I've tried using `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` but that seems to only get called after the user finishes dragging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your table view shouldn't change its height to accommodate the keyboard.

Instead, the keyboard should be presented overtop of the table view, and you should adjust the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` properties on the table view so that the lower table content is not obscured by the keyboard.  You need to update the scroll insets whenever the keyboard is presented or dismissed.

You don't have to do anything special while the keyboard is dismissed interactively, because the table content should already scroll down as the keyboard moves out of view.

Comment: Wow, is this documented? It would have been helpful to know ahead of time.

Unfortunately in my case, There's an additional view between the table view and the keyboard. Based on a certain set of conditions, the table view will either cover over this view or adjust it's height to display it.

I can possibly refactor my code so the in-between view pops out from below, rather than having the table view cover it, but that's a bigger refactor than I've got time for at the moment.

Either way, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'd rather this not be the accepted answer, but for those of you out there also having trouble with this here's what worked for me.

1. Create a custom subclass of UIView.
2. In the subclass's `willMoveToSuperview:` method, add a KVO observer to the superview's `center` on iOS 8 and `frame` on lesser versions of iOS (remember to remove the old observer, you may want to use an instance variable to track this).
3. In your view controller add a 0.0 height input accessory view to the view controller via `inputAccessoryView` class override. Use your custom `UIView` subclass for this.
4. Back in the subclass, in `observeValueForKeyPath:...`, capture the `frame` of the view's superview, this should be the frame of the `UIKeyboard`.
5. Use `NSNotificationCenter` or some other means to then pass this `frame` back to your view controller for processing.

It's a pretty painful process and not guaranteed to work in future versions of iOS. There are likely a ton of edge cases that will pop up later since I just built this, but it's a good start. If anyone has a better idea I'll happily mark your answer as correct.

Comment: show some code, i cant figureout how to add the observer

Answer (score 1):

This is what I come up to, insted of using notification I use a delegate:

```
protocol MyCustomViewDelegate {
    func centerChanged(center: CGPoint)
}
class MyCustomView: UIView{

    private var centerContext = 0
    var delegate: MyCustomViewDelegate?
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview)
        guard let newSuperview = newSuperview else {
            self.superview?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "center")
            return
        }
        let options = NSKeyValueObservingOptions([.New, .Old])
        newSuperview.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "center", options: options, context: &centerContext)
    }
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

        //print("CHANGE",keyPath)


        if context == &centerContext {

            guard let center = superview?.center else {
                super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
                return
            }

            delegate?.centerChanged(center)

        } else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
}
```