# Move toolbar with keyboard when tableView.keyboardDismissMode is set to .Interactive

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uikeyboard

I have a messaging view, with a toolbar like in the messages app. I am using AutoLayout and have a constraint from this `toolbar.bottom` to `bottomlayoutguide.bottom`, where I change the `constant` to `notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]` with a notification of `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

In this view I have a tableView, where I have set the `keyboardDismissMode` to `Interactive`. Now I have the problem that I cannot use the above method to move my toolbar down, as this won't be interactive (I only get one for willhide and didhide).

How can I make this interactive?

Edit: clarification

Using `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` is not an option, as I only get 2 notifications, once the user starts swiping down, and once the keyboard did hide. When I have the `tableView.keyboardDismissMode` to `.Interactive`, the user can change their mind and still make the keyboard go visible when I got a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification".

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onUIKeyboardWillHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: This is not an option, as I only get 2 notifications, once the user starts swiping down, and once the keyboard did hide. When I have the `tableView.keyboardDismissMode` to `.Interactive`, the user can change their mind and still make the keyboard go visible when I got a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. I will add this to my question.

Comment: I ended up using this and just disabling .Interactive on my tableview

Answer (score 4):

Sorry after a little search.

Sounds like there have no notification for UIKeyboard animation when you drag down the tableView.

There have 2 solutions.

1. Add your toolbar to inputAccessoryView.
2. Add a 0 height inputAccessoryView. And observe it's superView's frame(iOS 7) or center(iOS 8).  see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556264/uiscrollviewkeyboarddismissmodeinteractive-changing-tableview-height-with-keyboa)

   Or just use [open source](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&o=desc&q=message&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: I added the observer and got a notification, but the new value was apparently an `NSPoint` (a `typealias` for `CGPoint)`, but casting it to `CGPoint` failed with the error "Cannot cast `NSConcreteValue` to `CGPoint`. I think it might be because I am working in Swift and KVO wasn't meant to be used there. Any ideas?

Comment: You can get new frame in KVO Listener. More here : https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/blob/master/Source/Classes/SLKInputAccessoryView.m